# How do I embed a short movie clip on a web site continuesly looping

Tags: video, html5-video, flv, flvplayback

I have a short movie which I can convert easily (via ffmpeg) to a FLV file. In order to play this clip on a webpage, I know I have to *embed a FLV player*.

But I could not find a player *which loops the movie* automatically and continuously (like the many flash ads on the internet).

Or is it easier to loop a movie clip *via HTML5*? What file format would I then need to convert the movie clip into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JWplayer has a repeat variable.